# selecting a value from mysql table with 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

table: config

```
+--------+---------+
| c_name | c_value |
+--------+---------+
|   a    |    1    |
|   b    |    2    |
|   c    |    1    |
+--------+---------+
```

i have two sql queries:

```
$first = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT c_value FROM config WHERE c_name = 'a' "));
$second = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT c_value FROM config WHERE c_name = 'b' "));
```

i have these codes:

```
echo $first["c_value"]; // output will be 1
echo $second["c_value"]; // output will be 2
```

Can i do same job with 1 sql query?

Comment: As an aside, you should do yourself a favor and learn how to query MySQL using [PDO](http://us3.php.net/pdo).

Comment: @AdamBackstrom, i am developing an open source cms software. i can not use pdo. btw, thanks for your kindly suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Option:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT c_value FROM config WHERE c_name in ('a','b') ");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['c_value'];
}
```

*OutPUt*

```
1
2
```

**You can also use this(Without using loop):**

```
$O_Value = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT A.c_value as first_Value, B.c_value as second_Value FROM config A join config B on B.c_name = 'b' and A.c_name  = 'a' "));

echo $O_Value["first_Value"]; // *output will be 1*
echo $O_Value["second_Value"]; // *output will be 2*
```

Comment: 2nd option should be helpful on particular situations.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT c_value 
FROM config 
WHERE c_name IN ('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT c_value FROM config WHERE c_name = 'a' OR c_name='b' ");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['c_value'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c_name, c_value 
FROM config 
WHERE c_name IN('a', 'b');

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['c_name'] . " = " . $row['c_value'] . "<br/>";
}
```

Output:

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but, i can not use while function. i explained my situation in my post. i have to use echo.btw, thanks..

Answer (score 1):

And use mysql_fetch_assoc if you want associative array as a result.